# Replace chart dummy data with real data

Tags: javascript, chart.js

A machine at work sends out status data which I want to display in a horizontal bar chart.

The status can be either `ACTIVE`, `STOPPED` or `INTERRUPTED`.

Real data comes from: `current_array01.MTConnectStreams.Streams.DeviceStream.ComponentStream[8].Events.Execution` and the object holds the following example data:

```
{
  "_dataItemId": "exec",
  "_timestamp": "2023-10-23T15:16:08.4531+02:00",
  "_name": "execution",
  "_sequence": "135616878",
  "__text": "STOPPED"
}
```

Where `__text` can be either statuses explained above.
The real data variable will be read at an interval of 5 seconds.
As mentioned by @kikon, the object only has 1 timestamp whereas the chart has 2. The 2nd timestamp will the original timestamp + 5 seconds so the chart entries will follow each other up. Below is an example of how it should be looking.

[image]

My chart with dummy data looks like this:

```
// setup 
const data = {
  labels: ['Status'],
  datasets: [{
    label: 'ACTIVE',
    data: [
      {x: ['2023-01-01 00:00:00', '2023-01-01 01:00:00'], y: 'Status'},
      {x: ['2023-01-01 03:00:00', '2023-01-01 06:00:00'], y: 'Status'}
    ],
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(88,188,116,1)'
  },{
    label: 'STOPPED',
    data: [
      {x: ['2023-01-01 02:00:00', '2023-01-01 03:00:00'], y: 'Status'}
    ],
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(255,172,100,1)'
  },{
    label: 'INTERRUPTED',
    data: [
      {x: ['2023-01-01 01:00:00', '2023-01-01 02:00:00'], y: 'Status'},
      {x: ['2023-01-01 06:00:00', '2023-01-01 07:00:00'], y: 'Status'}
    ],
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(195,40,96,1)'
  }]
};

// config 
const config = {
  type: 'bar',
  data,
  options: {
    responsive: true,
    maintainAspectRatio: false,
    indexAxis: 'y',
    scales: {
      x: {
        type: 'time',
        time: {
          unit: 'hour'
        },
        min: '2023-01-01'
      },
      y: {
        beginAtZero: true,
        stacked: true,
        ticks: {
          display: false,
        }
      }
    },
    plugins: {
      tooltip: {
        enabled: false,
      }
    },
    layout: {
      padding: {
        top: 10,
        right: 20,
        bottom: 10,
        left: 20
      }
    },
  }
};

// render init block
const statusChart = new Chart(
  document.getElementById('statusChart01'),
  config
);
```

How do I edit the code so it takes the real data every second and adds it to the chart for a max of 100 entries so the oldest entries fall off the chart?

Comment: You can use the API to update the chart's data, for example `statusChart.data.datasets[0] = ...(your data here)...`. See also the documentation: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/api.html

Comment: I have absolutely no idea where to start as my javascript knowledge is very limited.

Comment: The line of code from my previous comment should update the chart with new data. The new data should have the same shape as the data you started with.

Comment: We don't where to start either, since we don't know how you get the new data points (do you plan to read that variable every x milliseconds?, do you make a handler function that gets called each time new data is posted?, etc.), nor what is the meaning of that object - it has a `_timestamp` key, but a datapoint in your chart has two

Comment: @kikon I updated my post with more information.

Comment: _"Real data comes from"_ - and that _is_ what, exactly? A static data source like an array, or some kind of actual stream where new data objects will arrive periodically?

Comment: It is a continuous stream that follows the MTConnect protocol: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MTConnect

Comment: Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pa36j4co/) with a version of your chart, animated by a simulated random data stream; I still don't get all the details of your setting, so this can only serve as inspiration. I set maximum number of intervals to 30, so one doesn't have to wait too much. One has to tweak the settings for the `update` animation, this doesn't look ideal, but that was not my intention.

Comment: @kikon Thanks you, this worked for me. Can you post it as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: I discovered that there are some issues with the animated chart update when the chart window in covered by another window; also, the axis animation is not synchronized with the data animation. I'll have to delve further into setting the right [transitions](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/animations.html#default-transitions) so it would work with animated update. I think I'll have the time to do that after a couple of days. For now, I published a first version of the answer 
with no animation `.update('none')`, which is safer.

Comment: I appreciate your help very much and will wait with accepting untill your final answer

Answer (score 0):

A simple and pretty standard way to update the chart is to just change the content of the `data.datasets` objects from the configuration object and then call [`chart.update()`](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/api.html#update-mode) method, where `chart` is the chart object, the result of the call to the `Chart` constructor.

In the updating function, the x axis for instance, can be accessed as
`chart.options.scales.x`; its properties may also be altered directly through `config.options.scales.x`, where `config` is the configuration object, the argument used in the unique call to `Chart` constructor (`const chart = new Chart(config)`).

The data structure that results from the description of your setting, is a [queue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Queue_(abstract_data_type)) and the javascript `Array` gets this done through its method `.push()` (enqueue) and `.shift()` (dequeue), no problems there. However, there are actually three
distinct datasets, one for each color (status), and knowing from which one to
remove the leftmost data point at dequeuing needs some coding that can't
probably benefit from a textual description, so it's better left to the listing
below.

It was fun to simulate the stream setting you describe, that is a variable
accessor (`current_array01.MTConnectStreams.Streams.DeviceStream.ComponentStream[8].Events.Execution`) that whenever evaluated might return a different value (that I set to change (or not) randomly after every 5 seconds). The fact that it changes its value without a function being apparently called, was done through the [`get`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get) syntax.

Here's a version of the code, in a code snippet:

```js
const DATA_REFRESH_INTERVAL = 5000; // create new data point after DATA_REFRESH_INTERVAL ms
const POLL_INTERVAL = 1000; // poll the stream every POLL_INTERVAL ms
const MAX_DATA_POINTS = 30; // remove old data points if there are more than MAX_DATA_POINTS

// empty initial chart
const datasets = [{
    label: 'ACTIVE',
    data: [],
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(88,188,116,1)'
}, {
    label: 'STOPPED',
    data: [],
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(255,172,100,1)'
}, {
    label: 'INTERRUPTED',
    data: [],
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(195,40,96,1)'
}];

const config = {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
        labels: ['Status'],
        datasets
    },
    options: {
        responsive: true,
        maintainAspectRatio: false,
        indexAxis: 'y',
        scales: {
            x: {
                type: 'time',
                time: {
                    unit: MAX_DATA_POINTS * DATA_REFRESH_INTERVAL > 120000 ? 'minute' : 'second',
                },
                afterBuildTicks(axis){ // filter out ticks that are not multiple of 10 seconds
                    axis.ticks = axis.ticks.filter(({value}) => value % 10000 < 1)
                },
                min: Date.now() - DATA_REFRESH_INTERVAL * 0.1, // -margin
                max: Date.now() + MAX_DATA_POINTS * DATA_REFRESH_INTERVAL +
                    DATA_REFRESH_INTERVAL * 0.1 // +margin
            },
            y: {
                beginAtZero: true,
                stacked: true,
                ticks: {
                    display: false,
                }
            }
        },
        plugins: {
            tooltip: {
                enabled: false,
            }
        },
        layout: {
            padding: {
                top: 10,
                right: 20,
                bottom: 10,
                left: 20
            }
        },
    }
};

// render init block
const statusChart = new Chart(
    document.getElementById('statusChart01'),
    config
);

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// random stream simulator
// current_array01.MTConnectStreams.Streams.DeviceStream.ComponentStream[8].Events.Execution will evaluate
// to an object of structure specified in SO question, that changes (or not) randomly every 5 seconds
const current_array01 = {
    MTConnectStreams: {Streams: {DeviceStream: {ComponentStream: Array(9).fill(null)}}}
};
current_array01.MTConnectStreams.Streams.DeviceStream.ComponentStream[8] = {
    Events: Object.create(Object.prototype, {
        _currentText: {value: null, writable: true},
        _currentTimestamp: {value: null, writable: true},
        Execution: {
            get(){
                const now = Date.now();
                if(this._currentTimestamp === null || now - this._currentTimestamp > DATA_REFRESH_INTERVAL){
                    this._currentTimestamp = this._currentTimestamp ? this._currentTimestamp + DATA_REFRESH_INTERVAL : now;
                    const r = Math.random();
                    this._currentText = r < 1 / 3 ? "STOPPED" : r < 2 / 3 ? "ACTIVE" : "INTERRUPTED";
                }
                return {
                    "_dataItemId": "exec",
                    "_timestamp": new Date(this._currentTimestamp).toISOString(),
                    "_name": "execution",
                    "_sequence": "135616878",
                    "__text": this._currentText
                };
            }
        }
    })
};


const allDataPointsOrdered = [];
// keep a queue of all data points in time order, so we know which to remove at dequeue

const addItemToDatasets = ({_timestamp, __text}) => {
    const t0 = Date.parse(_timestamp);
    const dataPoint = {x: [t0, t0 + DATA_REFRESH_INTERVAL * 1.02], y: 'Status'};
    const datasetIndexToAddTo = datasets.findIndex(({label}) => label === __text);
    datasets[datasetIndexToAddTo].data.push(dataPoint)
    allDataPointsOrdered.push({__text, _timestamp});
    if(allDataPointsOrdered.length > MAX_DATA_POINTS){
        const {__text: typeToRemove, _timestamp: dateMin} = allDataPointsOrdered.shift();
        const datasetIndexToRemoveFrom = datasets.findIndex(({label}) => label === typeToRemove);
        datasets[datasetIndexToRemoveFrom].data.shift();
        const shiftXAxis = Date.parse(dateMin) + DATA_REFRESH_INTERVAL - config.options.scales.x.min;
        config.options.scales.x.min += shiftXAxis;
        config.options.scales.x.max += shiftXAxis;
    }
    infoUpdateNumberOfPoints(datasets.reduce((sum, dataset) => sum + dataset.data.length, 0));
    statusChart.clear();
    statusChart.update('none');
}

let current_timestamp = null;
const readStreamUpdateChart = () => {
    const obj = current_array01.MTConnectStreams.Streams.DeviceStream.ComponentStream[8].Events.Execution;
    if(obj._timestamp !== current_timestamp){ // new object was produced
        current_timestamp = obj._timestamp;
        addItemToDatasets(obj);
    }
};
let stopped = false;
const interval = setInterval(
    function(){
        if(!stopped){
            readStreamUpdateChart()
        }
    }, POLL_INTERVAL
);

function stopAll(){
    document.querySelector('#button_stop').setAttribute('disabled', 'd')
    stopped = true;
    clearInterval(interval);
}

function infoUpdateNumberOfPoints(txt){
    document.querySelector('#info').innerText = txt;
}
```

```html
<div style="min-height: 120px; max-width: 90vw">
    <canvas id="statusChart01">
    </canvas>
</div>
Data points: <span id="info">0</span><br>
<button id="button_stop" onclick="stopAll()">Stop</button>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/4.4.0/chart.umd.js"
        integrity="sha512-6HrPqAvK+lZElIZ4mZ64fyxIBTsaX5zAFZg2V/2WT+iKPrFzTzvx6QAsLW2OaLwobhMYBog/+bvmIEEGXi0p1w=="
        crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/luxon@^3"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-adapter-luxon@^1"></script>
```